# Chrome adds attributes [requiredExtensions, systemLanguage] when logging a cloned SVGElement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

### Issue

Was working with transforms on `SVGElements` and discovered something I do not comprehend.

Basically I am trying to clone an exising `SVGElement` using `cloneNode(true)` and change its Matrix by using `transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix()`. This all works fine as long as I do not log the new `SVGElement` using `console.log()`.

### Here is an example

Have to check the actual console and not the inline output of the snippet.

```js
;window.onload = function(){
  var tSVG = document.querySelector('svg');
  var tSVGElement = tSVG.querySelector('#AL > g');
  var tSVGElement2 = tSVGElement.cloneNode(1);
  var tMatrix2 = tSVGElement2.transform.baseVal.numberOfItems ? tSVGElement2.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix : tSVGElement2.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tSVG.createSVGTransform()).matrix
  
  console.log(1, tSVGElement2);

  tMatrix2.e += 50;
  tMatrix2.f += 50;
  
  tSVGElement2.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tMatrix2)
  tSVGElement.parentNode.appendChild(tSVGElement2);
  
  console.log(2, tSVGElement2);
};
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 2253" width="811" height="661">
  <g id="AL" class="Touchable">
    <g transform="matrix(0.0736096,0,0,0.0736094,313.881,379.029)">
      <g stroke-width=".39819491" transform="matrix(2.51133 0 0 2.51134 -239.06 -636.03)">
        <rect width="397" height="397" x="95.790001" y="253.86" fill="#ccc" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.19458485" stroke-miterlimit="3" ry="0" rx="0"></rect>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M153.88 347.3H354.4v207.58H153.88z"></path>
        <path fill="#010002" d="M202.2 395.8c-3.22-3.24-4.84-7.17-4.84-11.8 0-4.63 1.62-8.55 4.85-11.8 3.3-3.23 7.2-4.85 11.8-4.85 4.6 0 8.6 1.62 11.8 4.86 3.3 3.3 4.9 7.2 4.9 11.8 0 4.6-1.6 8.6-4.8 11.8-3.2 3.3-7.1 4.9-11.8 4.9-4.7 0-8.5-1.6-11.8-4.8zm-21.32 79.6c1.04.8 2.26 1.22 3.64 1.22 1.4 0 2.6-.4 3.65-1.22 1.04-.8 1.56-2.13 1.56-3.98v-45.1c0-.7.34-1.16 1.04-1.4.7-.22 1.27-.33 1.73-.33.46 0 1.04.1 1.74.3.7.2 1.04.7 1.04 1.4V530c0 2.1.75 3.83 2.25 5.2 1.5 1.4 3.3 2.1 5.38 2.1s3.9-.7 5.4-2.1c1.5-1.37 2.3-3.1 2.3-5.2v-63.46c0-1.16.5-1.9 1.4-2.26.9-.36 1.6-.53 2.1-.53s1.1.18 1.9.52c.8.34 1.2 1.1 1.2 2.25V530c0 2.08.8 3.8 2.3 5.2 1.5 1.4 3.3 2.08 5.4 2.08 2.3 0 4.2-.7 5.6-2.07 1.4-1.4 2.1-3.1 2.1-5.2l.4-103.7c0-.7.4-1.1 1.1-1.4.7-.2 1.3-.3 1.78-.3.5 0 1.05.1 1.75.4.7.3 1 .7 1 1.4v45.1c0 1.9.5 3.2 1.55 4 1 .8 2.2 1.2 3.45 1.2s2.4-.4 3.46-1.2c1.03-.8 1.55-2.1 1.55-4v-47.9c0-4.6-1.54-8.8-4.66-12.5-3.15-3.7-7.37-5.5-12.7-5.5h-36.5c-5.3 0-9.2 1.9-11.6 5.6-2.44 3.7-3.65 7.8-3.65 12.5v47.8c0 1.9.5 3.2 1.53 4zm179.86-134.93c2.08 1.96 3.12 4.45 3.12 7.46v206.73c0 3-1.04 5.5-3.12 7.46-2.1 1.97-4.63 2.95-7.64 2.95H155.04c-3 0-5.55-.98-7.63-2.95-2-1.96-3.1-4.45-3.1-7.46V347.93c0-3 1.1-5.5 3.1-7.46 2.1-1.97 4.7-2.95 7.7-2.95h198c3 0 5.6.98 7.7 2.95zm-14.23 14.4H161.7v192.86h184.8V354.86zm-52.7 45.78c4.6 0 8.6-1.62 11.8-4.85 3.2-3.23 4.9-7.17 4.9-11.8 0-4.63-1.6-8.55-4.8-11.8-3.2-3.23-7.1-4.85-11.8-4.85-4.6 0-8.5 1.62-11.8 4.86-3.2 3.3-4.8 7.2-4.8 11.8 0 4.6 1.6 8.6 4.9 11.8 3.3 3.2 7.2 4.9 11.8 4.9zm-33.1 74.75c1.1.8 2.3 1.22 3.7 1.22 1.4 0 2.6-.4 3.7-1.22 1.1-.8 1.6-2.13 1.6-3.98v-45.1c0-.7.4-1.16 1.1-1.4.7-.22 1.3-.33 1.8-.33s1.1.1 1.8.3c.7.2 1.06.7 1.06 1.4V530c0 2.1.75 3.83 2.25 5.2 1.5 1.4 3.3 2.1 5.4 2.1 2.08 0 3.87-.7 5.38-2.1 1.5-1.37 2.27-3.1 2.27-5.2v-63.46c0-1.16.43-1.9 1.4-2.26.9-.35 1.6-.53 2.1-.53s1.1.18 2 .52c.95.34 1.4 1.1 1.4 2.25V530c0 2.08.7 3.8 2.1 5.2 1.4 1.4 3.24 2.08 5.56 2.08 2.1 0 3.9-.7 5.4-2.07 1.5-1.4 2.26-3.1 2.26-5.2V426.3c0-.7.3-1.16 1-1.4.7-.22 1.25-.33 1.7-.33.46 0 1.03.1 1.73.32s1.02.7 1.02 1.4v45.1c0 1.8.5 3.1 1.56 3.9 1.05.8 2.27 1.2 3.65 1.2 1.4 0 2.6-.4 3.65-1.2 1.04-.8 1.56-2.2 1.56-4v-47.8c0-4.7-1.6-8.8-4.84-12.5-3.25-3.7-7.53-5.6-12.84-5.6H275c-5.3 0-9.26 1.8-11.8 5.5-2.55 3.7-3.8 7.8-3.8 12.5v47.8c0 1.8.5 3.1 1.54 4zm180.6 49.16h-15.6V472.7s.1-2.13-2.7-2.13h-23.7c-3.9 0-3.2 2.55-3.2 2.55v52.52h-16.8c-4.9 0-.4 4.27-.4 4.27l29.8 36.1s2.5 2.9 5.1.3c3.6-3.5 28.9-37.2 28.9-37.2s4.5-4.4-1.4-4.4zm-61.2-140.98h15.6v51.85s0 2.14 2.7 2.14H422c3.88 0 3.2-2.56 3.2-2.56v-52.5H442c4.9 0 .4-4.2.4-4.2l-29.87-36.1s-2.45-2.8-5.02-.3c-3.5 3.6-28.9 37.3-28.9 37.3s-4.5 4.5 1.5 4.5z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<g transform="matrix(0.0736096 0 0 0.0736094 363.881 429.029)">..</g>
```

**Actual output:**

```
<g transform="matrix(0.0736096 0 0 0.0736094 363.881 429.029)" requiredExtensions="" systemLanguage="">..</g>
```

So as soon as I log the cloned `SVGElement` Chrome adds the two attributes `requiredExtensions` and `systemLanguage`, [which leads to the element no being rendered](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ConditionalProcessingRequiredExtensionsAttribute). As soon as I remove the `console.log(tSVGElement2);` on the clone it all works fine.

*Why does Chrome add those two attributes on logging?*
*IE11 adds it also just on the child element.*

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug. Have you reported it to Chrome's bugtracker or looked to see if someone else has?

Comment: @Robert Longson: I checked, but did not report myself yet. But it also appears in IE11 and Edge, just that the attributes are added on all child elements of the cloned element. You always have the same reply for me :-)

Comment: If you report a bug to a browser's bugtracker it might get fixed. What can we do for you here? I.e. what are you looking for in an answer other than "you found a bug"?

Comment: Confirmed by chrome, its a bug. See the updated answer

Comment: @ibrahim tanyalcin: Thanks. Sadly the answer to the IE support is still pending, guess they are not as fast as the chromium team :-) I will accept your post since you answered my primary question.

Comment: I know ie11 will get security updates thorough its lifespan, but I'm not sure if they will update browser behavior, especially for SVG.

Comment: @ibrahim tanyalcin: Likely not, since my other bug reports regarding IE11 and SVG are still pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR YOUR WHY QUESTION:**

I opened an issue for this, confirmed by chrome (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=873470), seems like this is a bug. And the reason is:

> I'd guess that this is caused by attribute synchronization, and the reason console.log triggers it is that it enumerates all properties and thus creates the tear-off/wrapper for systemLanguage/requiredExtensions - which in turn makes them require synching.

---

**pre-edit:** Seems like I was wrong about namespace not being inherited, one interesting thing is though  `‘requiredExtensions’` attribute should either be set to 'true' or not exist for an element to render. This is part of SVG spec @ 5.7.1 [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html) and normally the attribute (together with `systemLanguage`) is set on the `switch` element. Interestingly, consoling the **cloned** g within the main thread, adds this attribute with value `""` which translates to false and ends up the element not being rendered.

However if you wait for the event loop to finish and then log, the attributes are not there, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/8s97ophj/21/).

As a conclusion, if you clone a g node and console log it without appending it to the tree, these attributes will appear and the element won't be rendered. Though I do not know whether this was the intended behavior or a bug.

**SOLUTION**

Until the behavior is sorted out, monkey patch the appendChild, I had to use a microtask queue because apparently the attributes are added during calling appendChild:

```
SVGGraphicsElement.prototype.appendChild = (function(append){
    return function(node){
        setTimeout(function(){
        node.removeAttribute("requiredExtensions");
        node.removeAttribute("systemLanguage");
    },0);
        return append.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}(SVGGraphicsElement.prototype.appendChild));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/8s97ophj/

**SOLUTION 2:**

Obviously, you'd have to monkey patch other functions that modify DOM tree as well such as inserNode etc. In that case a mutation observer provides a more generic solution. You can watch multiple times with different parents, the same observer is recycled:

```
function watch(node,parentNode){
    var config = watch._config,
                callback = function(list,observer){
            list.forEach(function(d,i){
                            if(d.type !== "childList"){return}
                            if(
                                Array.prototype.slice.call(d.addedNodes)
                                .some(function(d,i){
                                    return d === node
                                })
                            ) {
                                console.log("added??");
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                node.removeAttribute("requiredExtensions");
                                node.removeAttribute("systemLanguage");
                            },0);
                                observer.disconnect();
                            }
                        })
        },
                observer = node._observer || (node._observer = new MutationObserver(callback));
        observer.observe(parentNode,config);
        return node;
}
watch._config = {childList:true,subtree:true};
```

**to use:**

```
var tSVG = document.querySelector('svg');
  var tSVGElement = tSVG.querySelector('#AL > g');
  var tSVGElement2 = tSVGElement.cloneNode(1);
  watch(tSVGElement2,tSVGElement.parentNode/*Or tSVG since subtree:true*/);
....
```

Once in the DOM, the observer is disconnected and the attributes are removed, you can modify the function and provide a list of attributes to change if you want. See this working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/21egmdn6/)**

---

~~This happens because you are not cloning the entire `svg`, but the `g`, at that instant the `xmlns` is not defined for this `g` because it inherited it from its `ownerSVG`. The moment you append it to its parent `svg`, the browser understands that it is part of SVG. If you console log after  `tSVGElement.parentNode.appendChild(tSVGElement2)`, it should output fine.~~

Comment: The attributes remain, sadly, even after appending it. I updated the snipped so you can see for yourself.

Comment: what happens if you remove the id attribute?

Comment: Are you referring to the parent #AL?

Comment: Yes that's what you are cloning.

Comment: I clone its child and not #AL itself. The group `<g>` I clone only has a transform.

Comment: See my edit, seems like you will need to take the console.logs for a clonedNode out of the current event loop for these attributes to disappear.

Comment: Yes, I wrote all that in my question already - including the section 5.7.1 to 5.7.4 :-)

Comment: It's a bug most probably, I wrote a temporary work around.

Comment: this workaround merely works as long as you really do not want to use those attributes tho

Comment: I am always open for better solutions.

Comment: The attributes are getting added on `console.log()` and not on `appendChild()` - it also happens on `insertBefore()`. Even if I do not add it to the DOM the attributes are there, yet one could argue that it wont matter much until the element is in the DOM.

Comment: I could care less about when they are added, this about removing the attributes that prevent the graphics element from being rendered at the next tick of event loop. I see your point about other functions that modify DOM tree such as insertBefore. See my second solution for a more generic way of dealing with it.

Comment: Also answered the why? part.